# Symantec backupexec for laptops & desktops

Tags: backup, server-message-block, symantec

I'm considering buying this product to pull backups from our laptop users to a SMB share. Are there other products out there that can do the same but are not so pricey?

Let me know

Thanks

Comment: Nobody? I'm now testing druvaa

Answer (score 0):

I tested Symantec's Backup Exec 12.5 DLO (Desktop & Laptop option) briefly and was unimpressed. BE won't allow you to back up to remote shares without buying the advanced backup to disk option, so you either have to back up to the server you're running the console on or have a NAS with iSCSI.

The client agent was OK, and you can be pretty granular with what locations are backed up, how much control the user has over the backup process, scheduling, etc. As always, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend going with a hosted option like Mozy Pro, Crashplan or BackBlaze. Traditional backup products are awful enough for servers, dealing with BackupExec and end users sounds hellish to me.

Comment: That's fine if bandwidth and traffic are not an issue.

Comment: Note that CrashPlan can be either hosted remotely, or on your own infrastructure.

Comment: @John The only real bandwidth issue for most users are PST files. Other than that, really not a big deal.

Comment: not everyone enjoys high bandwidth or unlimited traffic. In my case I would exceed the monthly traffic allowance, as well as swamp the bandwidth, long before I could complete a single backup of just one of my workstations.